# Make child window transparent to user input

Tags: winapi, vb6, button, controls, richedit

Is there a way to make input "pass through" a child window and reach its parent? My problem is this: I'm making custom control with a label that can be formatted. So, rather than trying to re-invent the wheel, I added a `RichTextEdit` control and applied the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` extended window style. It looks like what I want, but there are obvious focus and input issues. Is there an effective way to pass on the child window's messages to the parent or apply a set of styles thus making the child window appear to just be text drawn on the button?

Comment: I actually thought it would been simple to just send focus back to the parent window, but i underestimated windows. I ditched this attempt and replace it with:
1) Create a MemDC and draw the RichEdit Control onto it via a WM_PAINT call
2) TransparentBlt the MemDC onto the button

Thanks for the replies. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily by overriding the [WM_NCHITTEST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645618%28VS.85%29.aspx) message and returning `HTTRANSPARENT`.  Just be sure to turn off `WS_TABSTOP` also so the control cannot be tabbed into.

Comment: Wow thanks! I'll definitely keep this in mind, however i went with the TransparentBlt method and kept a 32bpp image of the text so i can apply image transformation through the use of a ColorMatrix with GDIPlus. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PostMessage](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/core/postmessage.htm) to send windows messages to your child window.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting TabStop False and Locked True?

Apologies if you have already tried it.

Comment: Disabled controls have a different look, but im using the WM_PAINT/Blt method. Thanks though.

Comment: Yes, but in this case you can always put it in a PictureBox and disable it instead, to retain enabled look with disabled interaction